# Call a tabPage from a separate window form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tabcontrol, nullreferenceexception, tabpage

I have literally just started programming VB today; so forgive my incompetence.

I currently have two window forms, one to navigate though different pages via TabControl (Which is called BusinessSalesPage.vb) and the other is separate (BusinessQuestion.vb). The second window form opens when a button is pressed on BusinessSalesPage.vb.

When the second window opens it has two buttons, I would like the user to be able to click one button which then takes them to the third tab from the TabControl that is on the first window (BusinessSalesPage.vb). Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class BusinessQuestion
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Friend WithEvents mainMenu As System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
Friend WithEvents TabPage3 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage

Private Sub yesButn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yesButn.Click

    mainMenu.SelectedTab = TabPage3()

End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the error I am getting:

NullReferenceException was handled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Edit

```
Public Class BusinessSalesPage
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mainMenu.SelectedTab = TabPage2
    BusinessQuestion.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the actual instance of the mainForm.  You currently don't.

You can try passing a reference in the constructor:

```
Public Class BusinessQuestion
  ' code...
  Public Sub New(mainMenu As TabControl, tabPage3 As TabPage)
    InitializeControls()
    Me.mainMenu = mainMenu
    Me.TabPage3 = tabPage3
  End Sub
  ' code...
End Class
```

Your BusinessSalesPage should probably look something like this:

```
Public Class BusinessSalesPage
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

  Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mainMenu.SelectedTab = TabPage2

    Dim bq As New BusinessQuestion(mainMenu, TabPage3)
    bq.ShowDialog()        
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this code and am now receiving this error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. It is concerning the BusinessQuestion.show() in BusinessSalesPage.vb.

Comment: @DannyCarman Can't see your code from here, but it sounds like you didn't create the object: `Dim f As new BusinessQuestion(mainMenu, TabPage3)` then `f.Show()` or `f.ShowDialiog()`.

Comment: @DannyCarman Pretty sure my first comment addressed the null problem.

Comment: @LarsTechm The Null error is not the problem the new error is "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." Which you did reply with "Dim f As new BusinessQuestion(mainMenu, TabPage3) then f.Show() or f.ShowDialiog()" Was unsure where this was needed.

Comment: @DannyCarman You replace `BusinessQuestion.Show()` with my code.  BusinessQuestion is your form class, so you have to create it with the `new` keyword.  Then you reference it with the name you gave it, which in my example, is `f`.  Try giving it a better name than that.  You might have to move the declaration of `f` to the form declaration of BusinessSalesPage if you need to reference outside that current method.  I updated the post.

Comment: Ah yes, I did try this, but it did not work so I assumed I did something wrong. When this code is run it stays in tabPage2 and opens a new blank window. Instead of the BussinessQuestion page. So it does not get the chance to work. Furthermore I got rid of InitializeControls() as it brought up that it is not declared and is inaccessible due to its protection level. Sorry to be a pain, I was rather hoping it was a simple fix and would not be to arduous for others to help, I realise it is a pain.

Comment: @DannyCarman Did you not create the BusinessQuestion form in the designer?  InitializeControls calls the procedure in the designer file that populates your form with the controls you placed on it.  Otherwise, your form would be empty, or you have to create all the controls yourself in code.

Comment: I had created it via the designer. I just did some playing around and changed it to InitializeComponent(). This has fixed it! It is working beautifully. Perhaps I bit off a little more than I could chew for my first day? Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1):

@LarsTech I tried this as well but mine is having issues with the code. On First Form when I type the mainMenu.SelectedTab = TabPage 1 I get error: "SelectedTab is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu and TabPage1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. On Second Form it doen not find InitializeControls, only InitializeComponents. I am in VS 2010 and here is my code:

First Form:

```
Public Class WCC
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

  Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mainMenu.SelectedTab = TabPage1

    Dim MSO As New MSO2014CC(mainMenu:=, TabPage1:=)
    MSO.ShowDialog()        

  End Sub
End Class
```

Second Form:

```
Public Class MSO2014CC
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Friend WithEvents mainMenu As System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

  Public Sub New(mainMenu As TabControl, tabPage1 As TabPage)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.mainMenu = mainMenu
    Me.TabPage1 = tabPage1

  End Sub
End Class
```